# Как выполнить setInterval при клике на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Но здесь что-то идет не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
function timer() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('timer');
  obj.innerHTML--;

  if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
    alert('I am soo soooooooorryyyyyyyy');


    setTimeout(function() {}, 1500);


  } else {
    setTimeout(timer, 1500);
  }
}
setTimeout(timer, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="ready" onclick="timer()"> Ready </div>
<div id="timer"> 50 </div>
```

Comment: И что же именно у вас *идет не так*?

Comment: @Cheg - угадайте. Вы профессионал, или не профессионал?

Comment: @Cheg функция сразу выполняется, а так не должно быть. Вы уж извините, если вопрос глупый, но я только-только начала учиться.

Comment: @Біпач поставьте закрывающую кавычку `onclick="timer()"`

Comment: @Igor, да, есть, но результата никакого.

Comment: @Біпач чтобы функция не выполнялась сразу, уберите последнюю строчку из вашего js

Comment: а в чем смысл `setTimeout(function() {}, 1500);`?

Comment: @Біпач а то, что слово "Ready" появилось, не считается?

Comment: @Grundy человек (пока?) программирует опираясь на культ грузовых самолетов, а Вы про смысл спрашиваете!

Comment: @Igor, спасибо огромное. Я стараюсь игру делать, но всегда ступор на таких мелочах, а так то получается.